# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)$. (WolframAlpha says it doesn't exist; I get $0$.)

Tags: limits

I have tried to solve limit, which wolfram says that DNE, but according to my calculations it is equal to 0. Limit is given below

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)
&=\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi-n\pi+n\pi) \\
&=(-1)^n\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi-n\pi) \\
&=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi-n\pi)(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi+n\pi)}{(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi+n\pi)}\right) \\
&=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{n^2\pi^2+\pi^2-n^2\pi^2}{\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi+n\pi}\right) \\
&=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi^2}{n\pi(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1}\right) \\
&=0 
\end{align}$$

It is because denominator of sin goes to infinity so everything inside sin goes to 0. as we know, sin of that would go to 0 too. And we know that $(-1)^n$ is bounded so we got that bounded * 0 has to be equal to 0.
Am I doing some mistake here ?

Comment: I think you are right. Numerical evidence agrees too

Comment: I guess WolframAlpha just doesn't assume that $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @Zag That's what the "[discrete limit"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+n-%3Einfinity+sin%28sqrt%28n%5E2%2B1%29+pi%29&assumption=%22LimitHead%22+-%3E+%7B%22Discrete%22%7D) assumption is there for ... though it doesn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need such a long computation. Once you write your sequence as
$$
a_n=(-1)^n\sin((\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)\pi)
$$
you can just observe that $\lim\,(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)=0$ and, by continuity,
$$
\lim\, a_n=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The step $\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi) = (-1)^n\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi-n\pi)$ holds if $n$ is an integer but does not hold if $n$ is not an integer.

Let's look at this another way.

$\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is unbounded and increasing.  When $n$ is large $\sqrt{n^2+1}\approx n.$

Suppose $n\in \mathbb R$

For large values of $n$ there will be values of $\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)$ that equal $1, -1$ and $0$ and the limit does not exist.

e.g. $\sin (\sqrt{100.5^2 + 1}\pi) = 0.9999$

If $n\in \mathbb N$ then for large values of $n$

$\sin(\sqrt{n^2+1}\pi)\approx \sin n\pi = 0$

Comment: Perhaps you don’t get the values close to $\pm 1$?

Comment: Notice that as $n\to +\infty$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $n\pi$ is a natural multiple of $\pi$ hence the sine never outputs $\pm 1$.

Comment: Indeed, but the question is why does W-A say that this limit does not exist?  And, it doesn't unless $n$ is an integer.  That is what I was trying to show.

Comment: @DougM Oh, that is clear now! Well I think this deserves a $+1$ then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be how $n$ is defined. Ordinarily we treat it as an integer variable, typically using a different letter like $x$ or $t$ if we mean a real variable. Then with $n$ an integer variable, the limit is zero as various answers imply. But if WA treats $n$ as a real variable, it will try to evaluate the "limit" $\sin(n\pi)$ for all real $n$ and, of course, this fails.

I do not know enough about WA to describe how to make it recognize $n$ as an integer variable, but I suppose that a brute-force way would be to put in $\lfloor{n}\rfloor$.